# How to add a tooltip to a Folium TimeSliderChoropleth map?

Tags: python-3, folium, timeslider

I have created a choropleth map in the Python library Folium using a TimeSlider plugin, and to this map I am trying to add a tooltip so that a user can interact dynamically with underlying data. I've used a GeoJSON tooltip before in Folium, but it doesn't appear the `TimeSliderChoropleth` plugin allows for a tooltip like a regular Folium Choropleth map does. Here's a screenshot of the Jupyter docstring for this plugin, and clearly there's no tooltip parameter:

[image]

In this example, I have created 4 imaginary polygons located in the southeastern United States and joined it with nonsensical data on a red-yellow-green color scale. So, as the user slides the bar, the colors change corresponding to the underlying population data.

My map takes just 2 data files: a CSV with some made up population data and a GeoJSON file with the geometry. The CSV is pretty simple and looks like the following:

[image]

The resulting `m2` mapping object, along with the timeslider, looks like this:
[image]

The slider & color scales work perfectly. But I'm unable to get a tooltip showing the `pop` column from the CSV for each time period for each polygon. I thought that adding a child element to the map object was the best path forward. Here's the full code I have to produce the above map:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimeSliderChoropleth
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

# create map object
m2 = folium.Map(location=[34.56729476051941, -85.9516678732555],
               tiles='Stamen Toner',
               zoom_start=6,
               zoom_control=False,
               maxBounds=[True])

# read in data, and recast a couple of columns
df2 = pd.read_csv('Book2_slider.csv')
df2['Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['Date']) + pd.DateOffset(1)
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).astype(np.int64)
df2['Poly_ID']=df2['Poly_ID'].astype(str)

# create the bins
bins=np.linspace(min(df2['pop']),max(df2['pop']),5)
df2['color']=pd.cut(df2['pop'], bins, labels=['#FF0000', '#FFA500', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00'],include_lowest=True)

# clean up the dataframe a little more
df2=df2[['Date','Poly_ID','pop','color']]
df2['Date']=(df2['Date'] // 10**9).astype('U10')

# create the dictionary that will assign the color bins for the choropleth
pop_dict = {}

for i in df2['Poly_ID'].unique():
    pop_dict[i]={}
    for j in df2[df2['Poly_ID']==i].set_index(['Poly_ID']).values:
        pop_dict[i][j[0]]={'color':j[2],'opacity':0.6}
        

# read in the polygons
test_polygons = gpd.read_file('tester.geojson')
test_polygons['id'] = test_polygons['id'].astype(str)

# create the choropleth
slider = TimeSliderChoropleth(
    data = test_polygons.set_index('id').to_json(),
    styledict = pop_dict
).add_to(m2)

# best guess as to how to create the tooltip
slider.add_child(folium.features.Tooltip(
   text=pop_dict
))

m2
```

However, I can't figure out how to dynamically access the `pop_dict` so as to show the population of a given polygon in a given timeframe in the form of a tooltip.